# Number of Orbits in Group Action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Let G be a group of order 15 acting on a set of order 22. Assume there are no fixed points. Determine how many orbits there are.

Comment: Do you know the relation between the size of an orbit and the size of the stabilizer of an element in that orbit?

Answer (score 6):

The size of an orbit $\mathcal{O}_x$ of $x$ in our set $S$ is equal to the index of the stabilizer $G_x$ in $G$.  Since no element is fixed, we cannot have an orbit of size $1$, and the only other possible indices are $3,5$, and $15$ by Lagrange's theorem.

So, somehow we need to figure out how some positive integral combination of $3$, $5$, and $15$ can sum to $22$.  It turns out there is a unique way to do this.  See if you can determine the size and number of the orbits from here.

Comment: I think this is a rather poor choice of hints. You have given all the details of the group theoretic part and only left a fairly straightforward calculation to the OP, which has nothing to do with group theory.

Comment: Once you pin down how many orbits of size 15 there are, the rest falls into place.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I apologize.  At times I am simply excited that I've seen the result, and fail to communicate it in a way that is most helpful to the person asking the question.  Hopefully user90240 can receive this answer in a way that is still edifying to his/her group theory education.